# How can I use emojis as drawables to show confetti?

Tags: android, android-drawable, emoji, shapes

I am using [Konfetti](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti) in my android project. Apart from regular shapes like Circle and Rectangle, I want to use other images. This library has an option to add custom drawables. I want to add emojis to shape, so that I see them as confetti. How should I add an emoji as a drawable or is there any other way to add?
This is how I am getting custom drawable and building confetti

```
        val drawableTriangleShape: Shape = Shape.DrawableShape(drawableTriangle, true)

        view_confetti.build()
            .addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA)
            .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
            .setSpeed(0.10f, 0.75f)
            .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
            .setTimeToLive(2000L)
            .addShapes(drawableTriangleShape)
            .addSizes(Size(22))
            .setPosition(-50f, screenWidth + 50f, -50f, -50f)
            .streamFor(100, 2000L)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your desired emojis to your Resource Manager -> drawable.
Then you should be able to use them with something like this:

```
val emojiDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable."yourEmojiID")
        val happy = Shape.DrawableShape(emojiDrawable, false)

...
...
.addShapes(happy)
```

Probably you have to add a non-null asserted call to emojiDrawable or check that it is not null.